# how to add soap header in soap request using apache camel

Tags: apache, web-services, soap

I am calling a soap proxy webservice having header (for authentication) and the body (having payload). Below is my soap request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prox="http://webservices.com/ProxyService">
    <soapenv:Header>
      <prox:authentication>
         <prox:user>admin</prox:user>
         <prox:password>admin</prox:password>
      </prox:authentication>
    </soapenv:Header>

    <soapenv:Body>
    <!-- Here is the body -->
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am using apache camel. I am able to create the body. But I am unable the add/set the header in the proxy request. In proxy when the request is coming it does not contain any header. It contains only the Body inside the Envelop.
Please help me to create the header in the soap request.

Answer (score 0):

You can form a soap header String like this

```
final String soapHeader = "<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" soap:mustUnderstand=\"true\" xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"><wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>abhishek</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText\">diamond2989</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>";
```

then during exchange add this header

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(SpringWebserviceConstants.SPRING_WS_SOAP_HEADER, soapHeader);
```

Change the String to suit your request

Comment: could you please share maven dependency of SpringWebserviceConstants

Comment: It seems you are not using spring camel context then, Please edit your question to include camel-context.xml

Comment: Please paste xml config where you are configuring endpoints for this service which camel uses Also code where for your exchange call

Comment: I am using spring camel context.
Even I have tried the above code.
But in proxy request the soap header is not coming.